# Tensorflow import_meta_graph returns 'tensor does not exist' error

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to import a saved neural network in Tensorflow. I saved it after training with:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, filename)
```

and in the script I use for inference, I restore it with:

```
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(filename.meta)
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

But during the `import_meta_graph` line, I get this error:

> KeyError: "The name 'dropout1/cond/dropout/Shape/Switch:1' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'dropout1/cond/dropout/Shape/Switch', does not exist in the graph."

I looked at the names of the tensors and operations in the original notebook in which I trained the model, and the names mentionned in the error message do exist. Moreover, I used the same code for saving and importing other models and it works. The only difference is that I trained these on an AWS machine, with an older version of tensorflow, while I trained the problematic one on my computer.

Comment: Which versions of TF are these? Might help in figuring out what changed.

Comment: When I run tf.__version__ I get 0.10.0 on AWS and 0.12.0-rc0 on my computer.

Comment: I played around with it, but it seems hard. You could potentially edit the checkpoints to match, but it would be quite a bit of work. Better to try matching versions, I think.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I forgot to mention something, and I just figured out this is the problem. In import_meta_graph I use the import_scope argument because I need to load 3 separate models in the same session (the problem I describe happens even when I load the model alone, though). And while the other models work fine with it, this one doesn't. When I remove the import_scope, it works.

Comment: Still you're right, using different versions is not a good thing. I think I will just run two different scripts.

Comment: I am having the same issue with essentially identical code, and I run both scripts on the same machine, so it's not a version compatibility issue. Further, if I iterate through tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() after restoring the model, none of the variables I have defined in the model actually appear in the list